# Wordpress media upload automatic refresh

Tags: media, uploads

I have added rotate image functionality in WP media upload. Image is rotating fine and saving is also fine, but when media upload popup is closed and opened again, it shows rotated image to previous image. If pressed CTRL + F5, then it shows rotated image. How can i get rotated image without CTRL + F5?
(added the query string also with url of image, but still showing from cache)

Comment: I think most other image manipulation plugins solve this by making a copy of the image and renaming it rather than modifying the original.

Comment: I don't want to make a copy, i am rotating original image and saving it rotated.